# Error while using formatstyle datatable r

Tags: r, dt

I have a reactive dataframe  as following:

```
       Apr 2017   May 2017   Jun 2017   Jul 2017   Aug 2017   Sep 2017
zz    0.1937571  0.1840005  0.1807256  0.1959589  0.2039463  0.2016886
aa    0.3518203  0.3634578  0.3670747  0.3676495  0.3680581  0.3657724
bb   0.10651308 0.11548379 0.11572389 0.11272168 0.11361587 0.11503638
cc    0.2481513  0.2579199  0.2623222  0.2673914  0.2579430  0.2550686
dd   0.06641069 0.06741159 0.07305105 0.07373854 0.07043972 0.07304338
```

I am trying to style the full table based on values(similar to this,[eg3](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html)).
Below is the code I have :

```
brks <- reactive({
    quantile(intrc_pattern_re(), probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm = TRUE)
})

clrs <- reactive({
    round(seq(255, 40, length.out = length(brks()) + 1), 0) %>%
        paste0("rgb(255,", ., ",", ., ")")
})

intrc_pattern_reshape <- reactive ({
    datatable(intrc_pattern_re(),
              options = list(searching = FALSE,
                             pageLength = 15,
                             lengthChange = FALSE)
             ) %>%
        formatPercentage(colnames(intrc_pattern_re()), 2) %>%
        formatStyle(names(intrc_pattern_re()),
                    backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks(), clrs()))
})
```

But when I do that I get the following error : `non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Could someone tell me what is that I am doing incorrectly? Thank you.
The output for dput(df,"")

```
structure(list(`Apr 2017` = structure(c(`zz` = 3L, 
aa = 6L, `bb` = 2L, `cc` = 4L, 
dd = 1L, Premium = 7L, `ff` = 5L), .Label = c("0.06641069", 
"0.10651308", "0.1937571", "0.2481513", "0.3090870", "0.3518203", 
"0.4697810", "Apr 2017"), class = "factor"), `May 2017` = structure(c(`zz` = 3L, 
aa = 6L, `bb` = 2L, `cc` = 4L, 
dd = 1L, Premium = 7L, `ff` = 5L), .Label = c("0.06741159", 
"0.11548379", "0.1840005", "0.2579199", "0.3043959", "0.3634578", 
"0.4719425", "May 2017"), class = "factor"), `Jun 2017` = structure(c(`zz` = 3L, 
aa = 6L, `bb` = 2L, `cc` = 4L, 
dd = 1L, Premium = 7L, `ff` = 5L), .Label = c("0.07305105", 
"0.11572389", "0.1807256", "0.2623222", "0.3030102", "0.3670747", 
"0.4766237", "Jun 2017"), class = "factor"), `Jul 2017` = structure(c(`zz` = 3L, 
aa = 6L, `bb` = 2L, `cc` = 4L, 
dd = 1L, Premium = 7L, `ff` = 5L), .Label = c("0.07373854", 
"0.11272168", "0.1959589", "0.2673914", "0.2984132", "0.3676495", 
"0.4759238", "Jul 2017"), class = "factor"), `Aug 2017` = structure(c(`zz` = 3L, 
aa = 6L, `bb` = 2L, `cc` = 4L, 
dd = 1L, Premium = 7L, `ff` = 5L), .Label = c("0.07043972", 
"0.11361587", "0.2039463", "0.2579430", "0.2970350", "0.3680581", 
"0.4828409", "Aug 2017"), class = "factor"), `Sep 2017` = structure(c(`zz` = 3L, 
aa = 6L, `bb` = 2L, `cc` = 4L, 
dd = 1L, Premium = 7L, `ff` = 5L), .Label = c("0.07304338", 
"0.11503638", "0.2016886", "0.2550686", "0.2998945", "0.3657724", 
"0.4909182", "Sep 2017"), class = "factor"), `Oct 2017` = structure(c(`zz` = 3L, 
aa = 6L, `bb` = 2L, `cc` = 4L, 
dd = 1L, Premium = 7L, `ff` = 5L), .Label = c("0.07651393", 
"0.11219458", "0.2025043", "0.2479362", "0.2866641", "0.3673334", 
"0.5121613", "Oct 2017"), class = "factor"), `Nov 2017` = structure(c(`zz` = 3L, 
aa = 6L, `bb` = 1L, `cc` = 4L, 
dd = 2L, Premium = 7L, `ff` = 5L), .Label = c("0.10724728", 
"0.15016708", "0.1857769", "0.2280702", "0.2691103", "0.3417920", 
"0.4948308", "Nov 2017"), class = "factor"), `Dec 2017` = structure(c(`zz` = 2L, 
aa = 5L, `bb` = 1L, `cc` = 3L, 
dd = 6L, Premium = 7L, `ff` = 4L), .Label = c("0.08775835", 
"0.1659323", "0.1945492", "0.2304338", "0.2958437", "0.29888712", 
"0.4493300", "Dec 2017"), class = "factor"), `Jan 2018` = structure(c(`zz` = 2L, 
aa = 5L, `bb` = 1L, `cc` = 3L, 
dd = 6L, Premium = 7L, `ff` = 4L), .Label = c("0.08016616", 
"0.1565603", "0.1753247", "0.2134740", "0.2811306", "0.34148205", 
"0.4315794", "Jan 2018"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("zz", 
"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", 
"Premium", "ff"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How is this data referenced in your code?  Does `intrc_pattern_re()` return the data frame you're showing?

Comment: @divibisan intrc_pattern() was a mistake. intrc_pattern_re() returns the df which I have mentioned the structure above for.

Comment: Did you retract your accepted answer? Are you still having problems with this?

Comment: @divibisan I actually figured that I was sending a df and not a column for df to get the breaks . I pass the right column from the correct df and it worked fine for me. Thanks your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you're getting: `non-numeric argument to binary operator` happens when you pass something that's not of type `numeric` to a binary operator like `+` or `-`. For example:

```
> 'a'+3
Error in "a" + 3 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

You're getting this error from your call to `quantile` because all the numbers in the data.frame you're passing in as `intrc_pattern_re()` are incorrectly classified as `factors` not `numeric`. If you look at the output of `dput`, you see that each line says `class = "factor"))`

Somewhere in `quantile` is a binary operator that is expecting to receive a `numeric` and throws the error when it gets a `factor`.

To solve this, you just need to make each column of the data.frame returned by `intrc_pattern_re()` into `numeric`.

If we load your data frame as `df`:

```
quantile(x, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm = TRUE)
Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

If we convert these `factor` variables to `numeric` (note you must first convert to `character` and then `numeric`) then it works:

```
df2 <- df %>%
    dplyr::mutate_if(is.factor, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

quantile(df2, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm = TRUE)
        0%        25%        50%        75%       100% 
0.06641069 0.15176539 0.25160995 0.34171451 0.51216130
```